# Preventing Docker Container CPU Resets?

Tags: java, spring, docker, tomcat

This is a tricky one and is a little hard to explain but I will give it a shot to see if anyone out there has had a similar issue + fix.

**Quick background:**
Running a large Java Spring App on Tomcat in a Docker container.  Other containers are simple, 1 for a JMS Queue and the other for Mysql.  I run on Windows and have given Docker as much CPU as I have (and memory too).  I have set JAVA_OPTS for Catalina to max out memory as well as memory limits in my docker-compose, but the issue seems to be CPU related.

When the app is idling it normally is sitting around 103% CPU (8 Cores, 800% max).  There is a process we use which (using a Thread Pool) runs some workers to go out and run some code.  On my local host (no docker in between) it runs very fast and flies, spitting out logs at a good clip.

**Problem:**
When running in Docker watching `docker stats -a` I can see the CPU start to ramp up when this process begins.  Meanwhile in the logs, everything is flying by like expected while the CPU grows and grows.  It seems to get close to 700% and then it kind of dies, but it doesn't.  When it hits this threshold I see the CPU drop drastically down to < 5% where it stays for a little while.  At this time logs stop printing, so I assume nothing is happening.  Eventually it will kick back in and go back ~120% and continue its process like nothing happened sometimes respiking to ~400%.

**What I am trying**

I have played around with the memory settings to no success but it seems more like a CPU issue.  I know Java in Docker is a bit wonky but I have given it all the room I can on my beefy dev box where locally this process runs without a hitch.  I find it odd the CPU spikes then dies, but the container itself doesn't die or reset.  Has anyone seen a similar issue or know some ways to further attack this CPU issue with Docker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in resource allocation in JVM containers, which occurs as it is referring to the overall system matrices instead of container matrices. In JAVA 7 and 8, JVM ergonomics are applying the systems’ (instance) matrices such as the number of cores and memory instead of docker allocated resources (cores and memory). As a result of that, the JVM initialized a number of parameters based on core count and Memory as below.

JVM memory footprints

-Perm/metaspace

-JIT Bytecode

-Heap Size (JVM ergonomics ¼ of instance memory)

CPU

-No. JIT compiler threads

-No. Garbage Collection threads

-No. Thread in the common fork-join pool

Therefore, the containers tend to become unresponsive due to high CPU or terminate the container by OOM kill. The reason for this is the container CGGroups and Namespaces are ignored by JVM in order to limit the Memory and CPU cycles. Therefore, JVM tends to get more resources of instance instead of limiting the separate allocation of docker allocated resources.E

Example

Assume two containers are running on 4 cores instance with 8GB memory. When it comes to the docker initialization point, assume that the docker is with 1GB memory and 2048 CPU cycles as a hard limit. Here, each and every container see 4 cores and those JVM allocate Memory, JIT compilers and GC threads separately according to their stats. However, the JVM will see the overall number of cores on that instance (4) and use that value to initialize the number of default threads that we have seen earlier. Accordingly, the JVM matrices of two containers will be as mentioned below.

-4 * 2 Jit Compiler Threads

-4 * 2 Garbage Collection threads

-2 GB Heap size * 2 (¼ of Instance full memory instead of docker allocated memory)

In terms of Memory

As per the above example, the JVM will gradually increase the heap usage as the JVM sees 2GB heap max size, which is a quarter of Instance memory (8GB). Once the memory usage of a container reaches to the Hard limit of 1GB, the container will be terminated by OOM kill.

In terms of CPU

As per the above example, one JVM has initialized with 4 Garbage Collection Threads and 4 JIT compiler. However, the docker allocates only 2048 CPU cycles. Therefore, it leads to high CPU, more context switching and unresponsive container, and finally will terminate the container due to high CPU.

Solution
Basically, there are two processes namely, CGGroups and Namespaces, which handling that kind of situation on the OS level. However, JAVA 7 and 8 do not accept the CGgroup and Namespaces, but the releases after jdk_1.8.131 are able to enable CGroup limit by JVM parameter (-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap, -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions). However, it’s only providing solutions for memory issues but no concern on CPU set issue.

With OpenJDK 9, the JVM will automatically detect CPUsets. Especially in orchestration, it further able to manually overwrite the default parameters for CPU set thread counts as per the count of CPU cycles on the container by using JVM flags (XX:ParallelGCThreads, XX:ConcGCThreads).